# How to keep wifi password safe?

Tags: wifi, router

I am looking for a wifi router that requires double authentication to connect. For eg. when a wireless pc is given a wifi password anyone can just go to wireless properties and click show password in windows.  I have seen videos of people deleting registry keys to disable show password option. For me this is not an elegant solution as I cannot do this to other people's personal pc.

I want to know if there is a router that requires double authentication to connect a device to internet. The first is wifi password itself and second is that admin has to approve the device through an app.

Comment: Please note this type of questions are off topic at SO. SuperUser is a suitable platform for these types of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many routers have the ability to do this by MAC filtering, which identifies client devices by their network device's MAC address.

More details about this can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_filtering).